# XmlPath mapping problems using eclipselink MOXy

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I don't see why the XmlPath mappings I have made below are coming out as null. Is there something wrong with my syntax? I used similar syntax elsewhere without problem.

Thanks for any clues.. John

```
<clip lane="-1" offset="2591065664/720000s" name="Music" duration="22304160/240000s" start="176794/48000s" enabled="0" format="r5">
    <adjust-volume amount="1dB">
      <param name="amount">
        <fadeIn type="easeIn" duration="1220/262144s"/>
      </param>
    </adjust-volume>
    <audio ref="r9" name="VoiceOver-26 - audio" duration="4639346/48000s" role="dialogue"/>
</clip>

@XmlRootElement(name = "clip")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Clip extends StoryElement {

@XmlPath("adjust-volume/@amount")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DecibelValueAdapter.class)
private Double adjustVolume;

@XmlPath("adjust-volume/param[@name='amount']/fadeIn/@duration")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TimeValueAdapter.class)
private TimeValue fadeIn;

@XmlPath("adjust-volume/param[@name='amount']/fadeOut/@duration")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TimeValueAdapter.class)
private TimeValue fadeOut;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to reproduce the issue that you are seeing using EclipseLink 2.4.0.  Below is what I have tried.

**Clip**

Your mappings appear to be ok.

```
package forum11937980;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name = "clip")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Clip extends StoryElement {

    @XmlPath("adjust-volume/@amount")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DecibelValueAdapter.class)
    private Double adjustVolume;

    @XmlPath("adjust-volume/param[@name='amount']/fadeIn/@duration")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TimeValueAdapter.class)
    private TimeValue fadeIn;

    @XmlPath("adjust-volume/param[@name='amount']/fadeOut/@duration")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TimeValueAdapter.class)
    private TimeValue fadeOut;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

Do you have a jaxb.properties file in the same package as your domain model with the following entry to specify MOXy as your JAXB provider?

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**input.xml**

```xml
<clip lane="-1" offset="2591065664/720000s" name="Music" duration="22304160/240000s"
    start="176794/48000s" enabled="0" format="r5">
    <adjust-volume amount="1dB">
        <param name="amount">
            <fadeIn type="easeIn" duration="1220/262144s" />
            <fadeOut duration="I/Added/This"/>
        </param>
    </adjust-volume>
    <audio ref="r9" name="VoiceOver-26 - audio" duration="4639346/48000s"
        role="dialogue" />
</clip>
```

**Demo**

```
package forum11937980;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Clip.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum11937980/input.xml");
        Clip clip = (Clip) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(clip, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.  Note that only the mapped portions from the input appear in the output.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<clip>
   <adjust-volume amount="1.0dB">
      <param name="amount">
         <fadeIn duration="1220/262144s"/>
         <fadeOut duration="I/Added/This"/>
      </param>
   </adjust-volume>
</clip>
```

---

**SUPPORTING FILES**

Below are the rest of the files needed to make this example run:

***StoryElement***

```
package forum11937980;

public class StoryElement {

}
```

***DecibalValueAdapter***

```
package forum11937980;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class DecibelValueAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Double> {

    @Override
    public String marshal(Double v) throws Exception {
        return String.valueOf(v) + "dB";
    }

    @Override
    public Double unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return Double.valueOf(v.substring(0, v.length() - 2));
    }

}
```

***TimeValue***

```
package forum11937980;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TimeValue {

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

}
```

***TimeValueAdapter***

```
package forum11937980;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class TimeValueAdapter extends XmlAdapter<TimeValue, TimeValue> {

    @Override
    public TimeValue marshal(TimeValue v) throws Exception {
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public TimeValue unmarshal(TimeValue v) throws Exception {
        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly and testing as well.

I tried remapping in a different way using a new class for AdjustVolume and now it picks up that element.

I turns out my DecibelValueAdapter is causing problems but failing silently. When it is a simple String value it appears.

I suspect the parser assumes failures mean the value is not present at all. Is that the default behavior? I didn't see any warnings.

Comment: @JohnBaker - The default is to soldier on.  Based on the experience of the JSR-222 user group we decided that failing on everything in the document that didn't match the mappings would make JAXB unusable.  You can set an instance of `ValidationEventHandler` on both `Marshaller` and `Unmarshaller` to get a handle on failures that occur.

Comment: If I upgrade beyond 2.4.1 the following mapping stops working - is null. Any ideas? @XmlPath("param[name='amount']")