# EclipseLink MOXy @XmlPath stopped working after moving files

Tags: eclipselink, moxy

I have this huge java class file with nested class coded everything in there.
After I got everything working the way I wanted, having the XML output I need... I split the nested class out to their own class file.

However, when I run the code, all of my @XmlPath annotation are ignored. Only the native ones from javax.xml.bind.annotation.* are still in effect...

Ok.. wtf, so I put all the nested classes back to the way it was, and ran the code again, and none of the @XmlPath (in fact none of the MOXy stuff works) annotations works...!

I tried to remove the jar, close eclipse, reopen, and re-add the jar back in, still no go.

How can I get EclipseLink MOXy to work again??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) jars are configured correctly and that you have a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html

Comment: OMG yes, I was reading your reply in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937980/xmlpath-mapping-problems-using-eclipselink-moxy) just now!!!


It works! That was the root cause thanks!!!

Comment: In the future releases of EclipseLink MOXy, is there plan to get rid of the jaxb.properties?

Comment: @codenamezero - The `jaxb.properties` file is the standard way of specifying a specific JAXB (JSR-222) implementation.  In environments such as WebLogic 12.1.1 where MOXy is the default provider a `jaxb.properties` file is not required:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/eclipselink-moxy-is-jaxb-provider-in.html